# Need help to create webforms page that has two forms (not nested)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms, master-pages

I want to create webpage that has two forms that post to server. Masterpage has a form that wraps only one logout button. outside form there are links to other aspx pages that each have their own forms. therefore there are no nested forms . however i get error 'A page can have only one server-side Form tag'
Here's my code

```
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/Default.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('default') }" runat="server">Home</a>
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/Status.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('Status') }" runat="server">Status updates</a>
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/Salotos.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('Salotos') }" runat="server">Salotų fabrikas</a>
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/VersionControl.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('VersionControl') }" runat="server">Svn logs</a>
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/Actitime/Actitime.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('Actitime') }" runat="server">Actitime</a>
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/Links.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('Links') }" runat="server">Recommended Links</a>
    <a class="small secondary button" href="~/Login.aspx" ng-class="{ active: IsPage('Login') }" runat="server">Login</a>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Logout" />
    </form>
```

Does anyone know how to solve that problem? If not then maybe I will make the logout through ajax request

Comment: Just remove the second form (form2) and it will work, if your button call the correct function on code behind

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebForms site structure requires only one form per page. Usually it is placed in Master page. So you don't have to insert any additional forms.